# How to programmatically set a server certificate for a self-hosted Web API (OWIN) app?

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-core, owin

When using ASP.NET Core I can setup a server certificate for an app using the following code:

```
var certificate = new X509Certificate2();

return WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
    .UseStartup<Startup>()
    .UseKestrel(options =>
        options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, 
            listenOptions => { listenOptions.UseHttps(certificate); })
     ).Build();
```

Is it possible to do the same thing with self-hosted Web API app? As I understand Web API is the predecessor of asp.net core and it looks quite similar. All I need is a small web server I can embed in any .NET app with SSL support. I don't want to install the server certificate to trusted root.

Comment: Web API 4.x on OWIN relies on http.sys, so you need to call HTTP API to configure certificates. If you do want the clients to trust the server certificate, you have to also install it to Trusted Root Authority, and there is no alternative.

Comment: @LexLi Thanks. I ended up using TcpListener - it doesn't use HTTP API and allows to obtain SslStream, which can accept certificates that are not installed in Trusted Root.